# Finding a file in an FTP server using ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I was wondering if there was an effective way to recursively search for a given filename using `ftplib`. I know that I could use `FTP.cwd()` and `FTP.retrlines('LIST)`, but I think that it would be rather repetitive and inefficient. Is there something that lets me find files on an FTP server in Python, such as how `os` can do `os.path.walk()`?

Answer (score 0):

No. Using `FTP.retrlines('LIST')` is the only solution with FTP protocol.

---

If you need a faster approach, you would have to use another interface. Like shell, some web API, etc.